# Mapping a list of elements to a range of an element from another list to create unique matrices

Tags: python, matrix, mapping

I am trying to "map a list of elements to a range of an element from another list to create unique matrices." Let me explain with a drawing.

[Kickstart-inspired question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdZAW.jpg)

I hope that it makes sense.

This is inspired by Google Kickstart competition, which means that it is not a question exactly required by the contest.

But I thought of this question and I think that it is worth exploring.

But I am stuck with myself and not being able to move on much.

Here is the code I have, which obviously is not a correct solution.

```
values = input("please enter your input: ")
values = values.split()
values = [int(i) for i in values]
>>> please enter your input: 2 4 3 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 6 4 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0

rows_columns = []
matrix = []
for i in values:
  if i > 1:
    rows_columns[:1].append(i) # The "2" at the very beginning indicates how many matrices should be formed
  elif i <= 1:
    matrix.append(i)
 
 rows_columns[:1]
 >>> [4, 3, 6, 4]

 matrix_all = []
 for i in range(1, len(rows_columns)):
   matrix_sub = []
   for j in range(rows_columns[i]):
     matrix_sub.append(matrix[j])
     if matrix_sub not in matrix_all:
       matrix_all.append(matrix_sub)
 
  >>> [[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I really wonder if the nested loop is a good idea to solve this question. This is the best way I could think of for the last couple of hours. What I want to get as a final result looks like below.

[Final expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uze8.jpg)

Given that there is information about how many rows and columns there should be on a matrix on one list and just enough numbers of elements to form the matrix on the other, what would be the solution to map(or create) the two matrices out of the other list, based on the dimensionality information on a list?

I hope that it is clear, let me know when it is not.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered numpy? If I understand what you want to achieve, it is converting a flat list of numbers into a set of 2-dimensional matrices. That should be real easy and performant with numpy.

Comment: Yes I know but I am not trying to use any internal/external module to solve this problem. I don’t remember the numpy method you are talking about maybe I can search it and find out. But I don’t know if using numpy really shows my competency in programming. Do you have any tips if you were to solve it on your own? Would you use nested loops just like how I had attempted or would you use some other logic?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. It is always important to be efficient, and as Python has many efficient modules, knowing when, and how to use the right one, will make you save time and effort, and show you are efficient at it.

Answer (score 0):

Without using numpy, here is one working solution, based on the input found in your code snippet, and the expected result listed in your final expected result link:

```
values = [2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
      0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

v_idx = 1
"""
As per example, the number of matrices desired is found in the first input list element.
In the above values list, we want 2 matrices. The for loop below therefore executes exactly 2 times
"""
for matrix_nr in range(values[0]):
    # The nr of rows and nr of columns are the next two elements in the values list
    nr_rows = values[v_idx]
    nr_cols = values[v_idx + 1]
    # Calculate the start index for the next matrix specifications
    new_idx = v_idx+2+(nr_rows*nr_cols)
    # Slice the values list to extract the values for the current matrix to format
    sub_elements = values[v_idx+2: new_idx]
    matrix = []
    # Append elements to the matrix by slicing values according to nr_rows and nr_cols
    for r in range(nr_rows):
        start_idx = r*nr_cols
        end_idx = (r+1)*nr_cols
        matrix.append(sub_elements[start_idx:end_idx])
    print(matrix)
    v_idx = new_idx
```

This gives the expected result:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

As said, numpy could very likely be used to be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Wow, that's actually more than I expected. No wonder why you said it is efficient to use Numpy. Now I want to ask you, when do you think it is appropriate to not use or use an internal module like NumPy to solve problems? If this was to be a part of the question needed to process the correct input hence it is not the ultimate requirement, then do you think it is better idea to use internal module to solve this part of the problem? Do you have tips when to use or not to use the internal modules available in Python? Is it always not looked good at using built-in modules?

Comment: Really depends on your requirements and on the size of the data you are dealing with. numpy is meant to be extremely efficient (like C code efficient) to format and process matrices. In the example you gave, it probably is an overkill, but if you had thousands of matrices to format and process, then numpy would definitely be the way to go. numpy is a very commonly used library, especially in Machine Learning and Math applications.

Comment: @Conan If/when satisfied with the answer, please mark as answered or upvote. Thx

Comment: Oh yes! I upvoted for your answer. Thanks a lot! It definitely is unnecessary to redo all the work that has been done. It is always important to start on the shoulders of the giants. We tend to take it for granted, but there is nothing wrong with using what they had left for us. Thanks, Malo for reminding me of that. I definitely am aware of how useful NumPy is in machine learning. Thanks a lot, Phillipe for your help! Though this question was about knowing how to map matrices from a list based on information of another, I learned a much more important thing to remember from you guys. Thanks!